# How to run two or more query in autocomplete textbox in php?

Tags: php, mysqli, autocomplete

code:

```
<?php
    session_start;
    include('config.php'); 
    $student_id = $_SESSION['student_id'];

    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $query = "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE company LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company_name ASC";
    $query .= "SELECT key_skills FROM skill_master WHERE key_skills LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY key_skills ASC";
    $result = mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $data[] = $row['company_name'];
        $data[] = $row['key_skills'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I am using autocomplete suggestion box when I use single query in the above code it work perfectly and show me result but now I want to run two query to get different data in a single autocomplete box but when I run this file it show me "null" output. So, How can I fix and get two different table data in single box ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: What happens? Are you getting errors? Have you looked in the PHP Error log?

Comment: Possible issue. You dont have a `;` between the 2 queries. Inside the string that is. i.e. `ORDER BY company_name ASC;";`

Comment: I try as you say but same issue @RiggsFolly

Comment: But we still dont know what the issue is. We need error messages

Comment: You also need to [read the manual for multi query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) you are not actually moving from the first result to the second. There are some other functions you need to call to traverse the multiple results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code was modified to get results from two queries.

Try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('config.php'); 
    $student_id = $_SESSION['student_id'];
    $data = array();

    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $query = "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE company LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company_name ASC;";
    $query .= "SELECT key_skills FROM skill_master WHERE key_skills LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY key_skills ASC;";

    mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $data[] = $row['company_name'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_next_result($con);

    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row['key_skills'];
    }       

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy @Karlo Kokkak

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query = "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE company LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company_name ASC 
          UNION 
          SELECT key_skills FROM skill_master WHERE key_skills LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY key_skills ASC";
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Do you know for sure that `company_name` and `key_skills` are the same data type?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I agree good answers always have an explanation but it's a straight forward question. Can we execute 2 queries simultaneously ? Yes we can. That's what I gave in the answer. Regarding the types. Why does that matter ? Can't we check the type in the while loop for that and then assign the values accordingly ?

Comment: UNIONS have to return the same datatype for each column in both queries